# How to read the assembly code dump by JIT C2

Tags: jvm, jit

Below is the assembly code dump output from JIT C2.
It performs a func call (`callq`), but in the comment section, JIT outputs a call stack.
Does this imply `inline` is only applied up to `SomeClass::SomeMethod`? Thanks for the answering.

```
0x00007f4a9f4f269f: callq  0x00007f4a9d0453e0  ; OopMap{rbp=Oop [288]=Oop [312]=Oop [112]=Oop [120]=Oop [128]=Oop [136]=Oop [176]=Oop [192]=Oop off=4132}
                                                ;*if_icmpeq
                                                ; - org.apache.spark.xyz.abc.SomeClass::SomeMethod@178 (line 87)
                                                ; - org.apache.spark.abc.xyz.OtherClass::OtherMethod@575 (line 561)
                                                ;   {runtime_call}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments show the current inlining stack corresponding to the given machine instruction.

```
;*if_icmpeq
; - org.apache.spark.xyz.abc.SomeClass::SomeMethod@178 (line 87)
; - org.apache.spark.abc.xyz.OtherClass::OtherMethod@575 (line 561)
```

In particular, the above comment means that the corresponding `call` instruction was generated as a result of compiling `if_icmpeq` bytecode at `SomeClass.SomeMethod`, which was inlined into the compilation of `OtherClass.OtherMethod`.

Here `OtherClass.OtherMethod` is the root method being compiled, and `SomeClass.SomeMethod` is a method at the first inlining level.